# Any android project in my android studio, layout preview showing highest like this

Tags: android, layout, preview

[This is my window in the android studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yqDu.jpg)

[image]

Comment: What is the issue? Add proper description when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your app theme from Light to Dark.

Alternatively, change the textview color to see the preview